# Adding "check" icon before text on notification

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a notification and I want to add an icon before the text, but I'm not getting it! My code looks like this:

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="nui://game/ui/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="notif-container">teste</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: white !important;
}

.template, .notification {
    display: none;
}

.notif-container::before{
    max-width: 5px;
    max-height: 5px;
    background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1828/1828743.svg);
    background-position: left;
    }

.notif-container {
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(28, 154, 212), rgb(0, 78, 167));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(28, 154, 212), rgb(0, 78, 167));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(28, 154, 212), rgb(0, 78, 167));
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(28, 154, 212), rgb(0, 78, 167));
    background-position: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
    font: caption;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Somebody knows what I'm doing wrong and how can I do it? I already tried various ways but without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [position: relative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) on the element with the class `notif-container`.

```css
body {
    background-color: white !important;
}

.template, .notification {
    display: none;
}

.notif-container::before {
    content: '';
    width: 16px;/*set the width instead of the max-width*/
    height: 16px;/*The same goes here*/
    background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1828/1828743.svg);
    background-position: center;/*Add this*/
    background-size: contain; /*Add this*/
}

.notif-container {
    width: 20%;
    position: relative;/*change this*/
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(28, 154, 212), rgb(0, 78, 167));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(28, 154, 212), rgb(0, 78, 167));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(28, 154, 212), rgb(0, 78, 167));
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(28, 154, 212), rgb(0, 78, 167));
    background-position: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
    font: caption;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="notif-container">teste</div>
```

Here is a clean version using [flex-end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) on the parent element.

```css
.notif-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 2rem;
}
.notif-container button {
    border: none;
    position: relative;/*change this*/ 
    padding: 10px 24px; 
    color: #ffffff;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(28, 154, 212), rgb(0, 78, 167));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(28, 154, 212), rgb(0, 78, 167));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(28, 154, 212), rgb(0, 78, 167));
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(28, 154, 212), rgb(0, 78, 167));
    background-position: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
    font: caption;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold; 
}
.notif-container button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 6px;
    width: 16px;/*set the width instead of the max-width*/
    height: 16px;/*The same goes here*/
    background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1828/1828743.svg);
    background-position: center;/*Add this*/
    background-size: contain; /*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<div class="notif-container">
  <button>teste</button>
</div>
```